# Error shows like " ERROR: Spider error processing " scrapy-splash, python

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

[error_img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A1TV.jpg)[error_img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0nV9.jpg)[error_img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tRGN.jpg)
Error shows like " ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed via http://localhost:8050/execute> (referer: None)". If I delete the script from the pycharm code it scrape the item. In the tutorial of frank he use the same script, where is the problem then? Can anyone solve this? Any help would be appreciated:
[setting_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wYC1.png)
I am using the below code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class AdamchoiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'adamchoi'
    allowed_domains = ['www.adamchoi.co.uk']
    # start_urls = ['http://www.adamchoi.co.uk/']

    # Copy and paste the lua code written in splash inside the script variable
    script = '''
        function main(splash, args)
          splash.private_mode_enabled = false
          assert(splash:go(args.url))
          assert(splash:wait(3))
          all_matches = assert(splash:select_all("label.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary"))
          all_matches[2]:mouse_click()
          assert(splash:wait(3))
          splash:set_viewport_full()
          return {splash:html()}
        end
    '''

    # Define a start_requests function to connect scrapy and splash
    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(url='https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed', callback=self.parse,
                            endpoint='execute', args={'lua_source':self.script})

    # As usual, we use the parse function to extract data with xpaths
    def parse(self, response):
        # print(response.body)
        rows = response.xpath('//tr')

        for row in rows:
            date = row.xpath('./td[1]/text()').get()
            home_team = row.xpath('./td[2]/text()').get()
            score = row.xpath('./td[3]/text()').get()
            away_team = row.xpath('./td[4]/text()').get()

            yield {
                'date': date,
                'home_team': home_team,
                'score': score,
                'away_team': away_team,
            }
```

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer this problem?